# How to save/persist and access data on client side in javaScript:Jquery?

Tags: jquery, javascript, javascript-framework, jstree

How to save/persist and access data on client side in javaScript:Jquery?

I am using jsTree component of Jquery:JavaScript.

In bind() of jstree, after selection of node I want to save "data"

```
.bind("select_node.jstree", function (event, data) { 
// where & how to save data ?
}

$("#Btn").click(function() {
// I want to access data value on click event
}
```

I tried to set data object in cookie and accessed same in     $("#Btn").click(function() {...
But can't access same data object

+

I also tried jQuery.data() i.e.
In bind() set data like....

```
jQuery.data(div, "selectedNode", data);
```

and tried to access in $("#Btn").click(function(){.... like

```
var selectedNodeData = jQuery.data(div, "selectedNode"); // Can't access
```

Any help or guidance in this matter would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

your solution is web storage, which is part of the HTML 5 buzz word , but it is not supported in older browsers , you can use [localstorage](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/11/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/)

Comment: actually, [localstorage has been there for a while](http://caniuse.com/#search=localsto) already

Comment: thanks for the comparison , didn't know it was supported on IE 8

Answer (score 0):

To persist datas *across multiple pages*, there are the `localStorage`, `sessionStorage` and the `cookies` solutions.

If you haven't got it working, then you got something wrong. I'd suggest you show us the code you used for your cookies :)

To share datas *on a single page*, you can use the `data()` in jQuery. But this way, you attach datas to a DOM element, not nowhere. Here is a sample:

```
$.data( '#myId', 'selectedNode', '#nodeSelected' )
// There, I attach the "selectedNode" key with the "#nodeSelected" value
// to the "#myId" element.

// To retrieve the data later, you have to use:
var el = $.data( '#myId', 'selectedNode' )

// Then, you can use the value like this:
$( el ).on( 'click', fn )
```